# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" with g++

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, g++, std

I'm trying to compile using `g++` and either the `-std=c++11` or `c++0x` flags.

However, I get this error

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

**g++ --version**

```
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: it's `-std=c++0x` with g++

Comment: @stefan Incorrect, both are possible. Which gnu version are you using? C++11 is only supported in >= 4.3.

Comment: Run `g++ --version` . Then post the version number here.

Comment: Also, which OS are you on?

Comment: @chris I think before it was `-std=c++0x`

Comment: @Antonijn, Yes, it was. I misunderstood your comment, sorry. I thought you meant the option was for 4.3+.

Comment: What do the sysadmins *mean* when they say C++11 has been installed?

Comment: That's horribly old. That version does not support C++11. Install a later version like 4.7 for C++11 support.

Comment: You can get the most recent gcc at http://gcc.gnu.org.

Comment: It is possible the sysadmins *did* install a C++11 capable compiler, but did not make it the default one. You can check which specific versions of GCC are installed by trying to auto-complete the command `g++-` in you console window.

Comment: @stefan My g++ version is **g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3** but still get the error, how to fix it.

Comment: @Gracchus I have upgrade it to 4.8, thanks.

Comment: GCC 4.1 is still available due to PowerMacs. Apple ships OS X 10.5 with GCC 4.1. I still use my old PowerMac for testing ancient the hardware and software. If you really want to punish yourself, then install Fedora 1 on a VM with GCC 3.1.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Seeing from your G++ version, you need to update it badly. C++11 has only been available since G++ 4.3. The most recent version is 4.7.

In versions pre-G++ 4.7, you'll have to use `-std=c++0x`, for more recent versions you can use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Is 4.8.0 like good to go, or is there an actual release in March or something?

Comment: @chris I'm sorry, it should be 4.7, 4.8 is still in-development.

Comment: @Antonijn, Ah, guess I'll wait a month or two. I prefer the stable releases, or whatever better word for it you want to use.

Comment: @chris Yeah. Or you just wait for the linux mint update manager to inform you :)

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy Yep, that's the one I'm using.

Comment: Same here. I'm using 4.7.2.

Answer (score 14):

Quoting from the [gcc website](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html):

> C++11 features are available as part of the "mainline" GCC compiler in the trunk of GCC's Subversion repository and in GCC 4.3 and later. To enable C++0x support, add the command-line parameter -std=c++0x to your g++ command line. Or, to enable GNU extensions in addition to C++0x extensions, add -std=gnu++0x to your g++ command line. GCC 4.7 and later support -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11 as well.

So probably you use a version of g++ which doesn't support `-std=c++11`. Try `-std=c++0x` instead.

Availability of C++11 features is for versions >= 4.3 only.

Comment: @Antonijn Correct, but not an option for everyone.

Comment: @Antonijn: There is software which is incompatible with versions > 4.1. E.g. ABACUS http://www.informatik.uni-koeln.de/abacus/index.html Sadly enough I had to use it once.

Answer (score 3):

you should try this

```
g++-4.4 -std=c++0x or g++-4.7 -std=c++0x
```

Answer (score -4):

I also got same error, compiling with -D flag fixed it, Try this:

g++ -Dstd=c++11

Comment: Why is this downvoted? What's wrong with the answer? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: @Veda for me at least (on gcc4.6.3), it definitely was not compiling with c++11. I wrote a simple 2 line program with `std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};` to test and it was throwing all sorts of errors over it (different errors than without the flag though, interestingly enough).

Comment: @Veda while this answer will compile, it very likely doesn't do anything desirable. The `-D` command line argument is equivalent to inserting a `#define` in your source code. So this command is like having `#define std c++11`. Can you then imagine how `std::string` will be redefined to `c++11::string`? Not very useful at all.