# Adding QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 to .pro file in qt not working(on linux 12.04)

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, c++11, qmake

Compiler output:

[main.o] Error 1

cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'

Comment: I think this might be due to the fact that I'm using Qt 2.4.1 or something like that. Downloading the most recent version right now from their website. I originally downloaded it from the ubuntu software center.

Comment: The problem is more likely the version of compiler on your system. What compiler is 'cc1plus'? Doesn't look like gcc to me. FWIW 2.4.1 is almost certainly the version of QtCreator. Any recent version of the Qt libraries is either 4.x or 5.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674597/cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c11-with-g

Comment: Nothing to do with Qt. Everything to do with old compiler. (also, no such thing as linux 12.04)

Comment: Update your QtCreator to version 3, Qt to version 5 and g++ to at least 4.3. and your ubuntu also needs upgrade, it's two years old.

Comment: @agilob: I do not follow. 14.04 is not out yet, and 12.04 is the last LTS, so that part is all fine ...

Comment: Is the issue resolved now?

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been having a lot of other difficulties with Ubuntu and am currently trying to resolve those before I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to update your ancient gcc version on the system. In fact, I am quite surprised that you have such an old version on your 12.04 Ubuntu variant. It should have 4.6.3 by deault.

What you could try is c++0x instead of c++11 and see if that makes it work. You could also fire up the gcc manual by issuing `man gcc` and look for the precise option.

Also, while we are it, you could probably simply write this in your qmake project file instead of such raw configurations:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already said in comments, this has nothing to do with Qt Creator version, but is caused by an g++ version that doesn't support C++11, for a little older g++ (but note that you need at least 4.3) the switch to enable the C++0x features implemented in the compiler is `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x` you can see the available features by following links in this [page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)