# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Tags: centos, g++, php-cpp

i am trying install php-cpp on centos 6,5.
when i run command make, i am getting error:

```
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 5.1e+05 s in the future
mkdir -p shared/common
mkdir -p shared/zend
mkdir -p shared/hhvm
g++ -Wall -c -g -std=c++11 -fpic -o shared/common/modifiers.o common/modifiers.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [shared/common/modifiers.o] Error 1
```

what i should to do for fix this?
my g++ is:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Thank you so much!

=== UPDATE ====

Fixed with upgrade gcc from 4.4 to 4.7

http://ask.xmodulo.com/upgrade-gcc-centos.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674597/cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c11-with-g

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That flag was not added until a later version of `g++` (4.7) to get the gcc 4.4 compat (as much as was there) you need to use the `-std=c++0x` flag.

Ref: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: Thank you so much. i upgraded g++ to 4.7 with flowed http://ask.xmodulo.com/upgrade-gcc-centos.html