# using C++11 in Mex with g++ 4.8 in linux

Tags: matlab, c++11, mex, g++4.8

I'm trying to call a function I wrote in C++ 11 from a mex script. The C++ code requires -std=c++11, and runs fine from the terminal. 
Here's g++ -v output: gcc version 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15) (GCC) 
I have Matlab 2013a for Red Hat.

When I first tried calling mex filename.cpp from matlab console I got:

> This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
>   standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
>   with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

So, I went into the */usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/mexopts.sh* file that matlab uses to get compler options and added -std=c++11. Now I get:

> cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

The full command gotten from `mex -v filename.cpp` is:

```
g++ -c -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread -std=c++11  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "mexMorph.cpp"
```

So, how can I get this to compile properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674597/cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c11-with-g)

Comment: that post is about g++ 4.1, which doesn't support the std=c++11, whereas I have 4.8 which does.

Comment: Maybe the `-ansi` is conflicting? Or maybe MATLAB isn't running the g++ you expect?

Comment: see my answer...very odd.

Comment: That is odd. Maybe throw a `--version` into the opts to make sure it's  using the g++ you think it's using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My testing indicates that `-ansi` and `-std=c++11` do conflict, as another responder has speculated. You could edit your mex options file (e.g. *~/.matlab/R2014a/mex_C++_glnxa64.xml* in my setup) and remove `-ansi`.
Also note that mex accepts a *-v* flag, which dumps a lot of useful debugging info.

Answer (score 2):

Try

mex CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -std=c++11" simple_example.cpp

Alteratively build your mex-file without directly running Matlab such as using CMake like the following github repo : [mex-it](http://github.com/audiofilter/mex-it)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense, but apparently using -std=c++0x will work. I think matlab does some checking beforehand, and since it doesn't support 4.8 officially it doesn't accept it even though the compiler would.
Can anyone back me up on this?

Comment: The g++ version being called by mex may not be the same as that being called from the terminal. Add `-v` to *mexopts.sh* to figure out what version is being invoked by mex. gcc4.8 definitely supports `-std=c++11` Or run `mex -setup` to see if it finds gcc4.8