# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" with fully updated gcc/g++

Tags: c++11, gcc, g++

I am aware that there are several related [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522387/std-c11-not-recognized-on-gcc-4-8-1) on this forum, but I'm still puzzled by this problem. I am using Redhat Linux. 
The gcc and g++ versions are -

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
```

Despite having the 4.8 version of gcc and g++, I receive the same error -

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

Is there some kind of additional configuration that is needed, apart from simply installing gcc/g++ 4.8 version?

Comment: Can you post the full `cc1plus` invocation when you run the C++ compiler with the `-v` option? Thanks.

Comment: You need g++-4.9 or newer to get `-std=c++11`.   With g++-4.8 you only `c++0x`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11" with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674597/cc1plus-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-std-c11-with-g)

Comment: @knst The solution mentioned in that post is that having a gcc version of 4.3 or higher would allow for c++11. But that doesn't seem to work in this situation.