# Rcpp with c++11 flag in Windows: unrecognized command line option -std=c++11

Tags: c++11, rcpp

I wrote a Rcpp code which works fine in linux, But When I want to run it on University labs which have Windows machines.
I get this error:

```
error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'
```

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14674646/2454690) I used `-std=c++0x`, But it not working on my code.

**Question is**: How Can I update g++ in windows. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What's the compiler version?

Comment: @kabanus `4.9.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R supports the *one* version of `g++` that ships in the [Rtools bundle](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) associated with each R release, currently `g++` 4.9.3.

Changing that is "possibly in theory but really hard in practive".

Try to adapt your code to `g++` 4.9.3.   I have in one case backported something missing from the C++ standard library shipping with `g++`.